# Change Timeline view to show literal dates and times

Tags: support, timestamps, timeline

I mostly like the feature that converts all the dates/times to instead show 'x minutes/hours/days ago', but a recent experience made me wish there was a way to see the actual dates/times that posts were made.

I had answered a question, then made an edit to include some new information. Approximately 30 mins after my edit another user left a comment (and subsequently made a post) containing the same info.

For about two days I had no idea whether the user had not noticed my updated answer, or it was one of those cases where we both made the discovery at about the same time.  Both my update and his comment only gave a rough idea that it was about the same time. (For the curious, question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2904104/timeline)

Maybe the Timeline view could show literal dates and times instead of reformatting it the fancy way. Or is there already another way I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover over any time value, it will show you the timestamp as a tooltip. For example, I can see you posted this question on `2010-05-28 18:01:21Z`. Works pretty much anywhere a time is shown, whether it's relative (X minutes ago) or an actual date.